# R | replace environment name by a variable

Tags: r

a newbie question: I want to write a universal function which saves variables in a new environment. The name of the environment I want to give as argument in to the function.

```
#create environment
my.env <- new.env()
#variable to store the name of the environment
env_n<-"my.env"
# now safe a  variable a with value 1 to my.env
my.env$a=1 #working
```

But I want to have a universal solution which works for many cases, there for I want to use the variable which stores the name of the environment. Something like:

```
#Things I tried
env_n$a=1 #not working
assign(a, 1, envir=env_n)
```

Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `assign()` should be a character value, not a symbol. And the `envir=` parameter should be a proper environment, not a character value. If you want to get the value of a variable given a character value of the variable name, you use `get()`. This should work

```
assign("a", 1, envir=get(env_n))
```

But this is a very unusual operation for a "newbie" to be using. I would take a step back and look and what you are trying to do and see if there isn't a more "R-like" way to do things.

Comment: I totally agree with MrFlick. Those concepts are not easy to grasp... By analogy, we wouldn't think of using words like "semiotics" in an English 101 course. (but see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html when you're comfortable enough with the basics)

Comment: A last question: how would the "my.env$a" (reading the asigned value) equivalent with env_n work?

Comment: It wouldn't. If you want to do assignment with character values, you need to use `assign()`